What exactly is aws load balancer "Protocol : Port"?
I have never been able to figure out what this configuration is or does when creating load balancers.
The documentation says

Choose a protocol for your target group that corresponds to the Load Balancer type that will route traffic to it. Some protocols now include anomaly detection for the targets and you can set mitigation options once your target group is created. This choice cannot be changed after creation

Am I setting the port that I want on the external facing load balancer or am I setting the port that the EC2 instance uses internally?
I've tried both ways and things see to work regardless. So I do not understand what "Protocol : Port" is or what value to set it to.
screen shot of the protocol port setting

Load balancers connect to back end servers / service, defined by a target group. Requests are sent from the load balancer to the back the servers using the port and protocol in that dialog. For example https on 443 would be standard, but you can do http or https on any port you like.
